# MySQL - limiting the scope of a count in the subquery, and then doing a SUM() on it

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I have two tables; one for customer orders and one for kit on those orders. I'm trying to get an idea of percentage of the kit that's shipped from each order, and I'm having trouble producing the SQL queries to count the line items (and sum their quantities). I've reduced the problem to a simple set of data, and I'm pretty sure that the problem is in my subqueries... but I don't know how to apply a SUM on the results of those subqueries, and I also suspect they're applying to the whole dataset rather than being limited by my join:

Here's the complete example which shows my problem (I'm using the quantity column as a proxy for whether the line item should be ignored or not).

```
/*DROP TABLE customer_order;
DROP TABLE customer_item;
*/
CREATE TABLE customer_order (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    customer varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
CREATE TABLE customer_item (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    order_id INT NOT NULL,
    quantity INT,
    part_number varchar(255),
    description varchar(255),
    shipment_date DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    INDEX order_id_idx (order_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO customer_order VALUES(1, "Spronketts LTD");
INSERT INTO customer_order VALUES(2, "Widgets Inc.");
INSERT INTO customer_order VALUES(3, "Frobizz PLC");
/*Create an entirely shipped order with some junk lines*/
INSERT INTO customer_item VALUES(NULL, 1, 1,    "01-ABC", "Spline bender",    "2018-01-01T12:00:00");
INSERT INTO customer_item VALUES(NULL, 1, 3,    "02-XYZ", "NURB reticulator", "2018-01-01T12:00:00");
INSERT INTO customer_item VALUES(NULL, 1, NULL, "",       "Junk Text",        NULL);
INSERT INTO customer_item VALUES(NULL, 1, NULL, "",       "Foobar",           NULL);
/*Create a 90% shipped order (1 item of 10 outstanding)*/
INSERT INTO customer_item VALUES(NULL, 2, 1,    "01-ABC", "Spline bender",    "2018-01-01T12:00:00");
INSERT INTO customer_item VALUES(NULL, 2, 3,    "02-XYZ", "NURB reticulator", "2018-01-01T12:00:00");
INSERT INTO customer_item VALUES(NULL, 2, 5,    "03-XYZ", "Doohickey",        "2018-01-01T12:00:00");
INSERT INTO customer_item VALUES(NULL, 2, 1,    "04-XYZ", "Whatsit",          NULL);
/*Now create a 0% shipped order*/
INSERT INTO customer_item VALUES(NULL, 3, 1,    "01-ABC", "Spline bender",    NULL);
INSERT INTO customer_item VALUES(NULL, 3, 1,    "02-XYZ", "NURB reticulator", NULL);
INSERT INTO customer_item VALUES(NULL, 3, 1,    "03-XYZ", "Doohickey",        NULL);
INSERT INTO customer_item VALUES(NULL, 3, 1,    "04-XYZ", "Whatsit",          NULL);

SELECT customer, order_id AS id,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer_item WHERE quantity IS NOT NULL) AS total_items,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer_item WHERE quantity IS NOT NULL AND shipment_date IS NOT NULL) AS shipped_items
FROM customer_item LEFT JOIN customer_order ON customer_item.order_id=customer_order.id;

/* Hoping to see:
+----------------+---+----+---+
| Spronketts LTD | 1 | 4  | 4 |
| Widgets Inc.   | 2 | 10 | 9 |
| Frobizz PLC    | 3 | 4  | 0 |
+----------------+---+----+---+
But I get
+----------------+----+-------------+---------------+
| customer       | id | total_items | shipped_items |
+----------------+----+-------------+---------------+
| Spronketts LTD |  1 |          10 |             5 |
| Spronketts LTD |  1 |          10 |             5 |
| Spronketts LTD |  1 |          10 |             5 |
| Spronketts LTD |  1 |          10 |             5 |
| Widgets Inc.   |  2 |          10 |             5 |
| Widgets Inc.   |  2 |          10 |             5 |
| Widgets Inc.   |  2 |          10 |             5 |
| Widgets Inc.   |  2 |          10 |             5 |
| Frobizz PLC    |  3 |          10 |             5 |
| Frobizz PLC    |  3 |          10 |             5 |
| Frobizz PLC    |  3 |          10 |             5 |
| Frobizz PLC    |  3 |          10 |             5 |
+----------------+----+-------------+---------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need sum not count and conditional sum for `shipped_items`

```
SELECT customer, order_id AS id,
SUM(quantity) total_items,
SUM(CASE WHEN shipment_date IS NOT NULL THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) shipped_items
FROM customer_item 
LEFT JOIN customer_order ON customer_item.order_id=customer_order.id
GROUP BY customer, order_id
ORDER BY order_id
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb691a/8)

*Output*

```
customer            id  total_items  shipped_items  
--------------  ------  -----------  ---------------
Spronketts LTD       1            4                4
Widgets Inc.         2           10                9
Frobizz PLC          3            4                0
```

Comment: That looks like it's exactly what I need. I hadn't seen CASE before, and that's a clever use of SUM(quantity) where I'd been convinced it's just a proxy marker. Thanks.